# SQLite build query from multiple tables column '_id' does not exist

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have two tables and I want to build query based on those tables columns. First of all here's how I create tables.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Constants.PRODUCTS_INFO +
                " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Constants.BARCODE + " BIGINT);");

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +
                Constants.FOOD_ADDITIVES_TABLE + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                Constants.FOOD_ADDITIVES + " TEXT, " + Constants.PRODUCT_ID + " INTEGER);");
```

As you can see both tables have their own `_id`.
So now I want to build a query

```
String q = "SELECT " + Constants.FOOD_ADDITIVES + " FROM " +
                Constants.FOOD_ADDITIVES_TABLE + " INNER JOIN " + Constants.PRODUCTS_INFO + " ON " +
                Constants.PRODUCTS_INFO + "._id = " + Constants.PRODUCT_ID + " WHERE " + Constants.BARCODE + " = ?";

cursor = db.rawQuery(q, new String[]{barcode});


 adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,
                      new String[]{Constants.BARCODE}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
```

And after this I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

dumpCursor Output:

```
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@8e56edf
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: 0 {
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out:    FOOD_ADDITIVES=E621
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: }
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: 1 {
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out:    FOOD_ADDITIVES=E301
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: }
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: 2 {
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out:    FOOD_ADDITIVES=E120
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: }
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: 3 {
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out:    FOOD_ADDITIVES=E250
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: }
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: 4 {
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out:    FOOD_ADDITIVES=E316
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: }
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: 5 {
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out:    FOOD_ADDITIVES=E250
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: }
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode I/System.out: <<<<<
11-16 21:14:58.241 18948-18948/barcode2.android.com.barcode D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

Comment: when not sure what's inside your `Cursor` call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor)`

Comment: @pskink I don't know what you mean, but I think that the problem is `_id` is not found in the table.

Comment: just call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor)` and see the logcat

Comment: I think you misspell the query string, try changing  **Constants.PRODUCTS_INFO + "._id = " + Constants.PRODUCT_ID** with 
    **Constants.PRODUCTS_INFO + "._id = " + Constants.FOOD_ADDITIVES_TABLE+"."+Constants.PRODUCT_ID**.

Comment: @Dhaval Patel Sorry, I have try this earlier but still the same error.

Comment: try this for testing SELECT " + Constants.FOOD_ADDITIVES + ", _id FROM

Comment: @avjr nope the same error

Comment: can you post what is the output of `dumpCursor` (or at least first row) ?

Comment: and what about this? SELECT " + Constants.FOOD_ADDITIVES + " AS _id FROM ...

Comment: To @pskink I just have updated my post

Comment: so as you can see there is on coulumn in your cursor: `"FOOD_ADDITIVES"`, what `CursorAdapter` requires is a column called `"_id"`: you need to add it to your "SELECT" query

Comment: @pskink Thank You very much. I spend 2 hours trying to fix this problem. Could you write your comment as the answer, so I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have got `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

this column is required by a `CursorAdapter`, what you need is to add a column called `"_id"` to your "SELCT" query, when you are not sure what's inside your `Cursor` call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor()` to see its columns